# How to label training data for CNN?

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, conv-neural-network

I'm trying to design an neural network that predicts a photo image based on 5 distinct film stock. I have 5000 total images. 4000 training and 1000 testing. I've stored images into two sub-folders for training and testing data.

```
training_dir = r'C:\...\Training Set'
test_dir = r'C:\...\Test Set'
```

I'm able to collect the training images using skimage io.ImageCollection.

```
   folders = []
for image_path in os.scandir(training_dir):
    img = io.ImageCollection(os.path.join(training_dir, image_path, '*.jpg'))
    folders.append(img)
```

I then collect the training images based on class and apply a loop to save image data into a list.

```
    ektachrome = folders[0]
    HP5 = folders[1]
    LomoP = folders[2]
    Trix = folders[3]
    velvia = folders[4]

images = []
for i in range(0, 800):
    ekta = ektachrome[i]
    images.append(ekta)
    hp5 = HP5[i]
    images.append(hp5)
    lomo = LomoP[i]
    images.append(lomo)
    trix = Trix[i]
    images.append(trix)
    Velvia = velvia[i]
    images.append(Velvia)
```

When I put the list of training images into an array `np.asarray(images).shape`, I get a shape of (4000,). I'm having trouble labeling the data. Here are my labels.

```
label = {'Ektachrome':1, 'HP5':2, 'Lomochrome Purple':3, 'Tri-X':4, 'Velvia 50':5}
```

How do I label my images?

Answer (score 1):

As per my understanding, your Images should be Categorized based on the Class Names, as shown below (since you've mentioned `Folders[0]`, `Folders[1]`, etc.):

[image]

In that case, you can use the below code for Labelling the Images.

```
Ektachrome_dir = train_dir / 'Ektachrome'
HP5_dir = train_dir / 'HP5'
Lomochrome_Purple_dir = train_dir / 'Lomochrome Purple'
Tri_X_dir = train_dir / 'Tri-X'
Velvia_50_dir = train_dir / 'Velvia 50'

# Get the list of all the images
Ektachrome_Images = Ektachrome_dir.glob('*.jpeg')
HP5_Images = HP5_dir.glob('*.jpeg')
Lomochrome_Purple_Images = Lomochrome_Purple_dir.glob('*.jpeg')
Tri_X_Images = Tri_X_dir.glob('*.jpeg')
Velvia_50_Images = Velvia_50_dir.glob('*.jpeg')

# An empty list. We will insert the data into this list in (img_path, label) format
train_data = []

for img in Ektachrome_Images:
    train_data.append((img,1))

for img in HP5_Images:
    train_data.append((img, 2))

for img in Lomochrome_Purple_Images:
    train_data.append((img, 3))

for img in Tri_X_Images:
    train_data.append((img, 4))

for img in Velvia_50_Images:
    train_data.append((img, 5))
```